# Mysql rank different students with multiple subject results in same table

Tags: mysql, ranking

I want to rank the students based on the subject, and their total overall for that particular subject. Query works for all subjects but when I specify the `where` clause, I only get the rank of the user specified in the `where` clause and rank is always 1 seems it's not checking the other ids

[image]

```
SELECT 
    Student_id,
    Subject,
    Total_Overal,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Subject ORDER BY Total_Overal DESC) as StudentRank
FROM
    exams 
WHERE 
    Student_id = "155676" 
    AND Subject = "French";
```

Comment: "seems it's not checking the other ids"  Well, you put the `WHERE` clause.  What's left is just rows satisfying the `WHERE`.

Comment: Order of operation the where executes before the rank so as Eric points out, the where calause elimintes what you're after.  Put the select and from inside it's own select, or in a CTE and have teh where clause outside the subquery or as a seperate query against the CTE.

Answer (score 1):

Because the where clause results in only one row of results, the ranking will always be 1. You need to add another layer of SELECT around:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT Student_id,
    Subject,
    Total_Overal,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Subject ORDER BY Total_Overal DESC) as StudentRank
FROM exams) t
WHERE Student_id="155676" and Subject="French";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you understand SQL order of execution, you will understand why you get what you get.  `WHERE` is evaluated before `SELECT`.

```
FROM and JOIN.
WHERE.
GROUP BY.
ROLLUP , CUBE , GROUPING SETS.
HAVING.
OVER (e.g., Window Functions)
SELECT.
DISTINCT.
```

https://vladmihalcea.com/sql-operation-order/